# keeping old contract when chnging to new phone

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I want to install WhatsApp on my new phone (same SIM card and number). Can I do this and still keep my old WhatsApp account, which I registered before they were bought by Facebook?

Comment: What contract is this that you're talking about?

Comment: Hi, just the normal log in for Whatsapp, perhaps contract was the wrong word but I joined them Whatsapp long before they had the colaboration with facebook so my details are not shared with them (facebook).

Answer (score 0):

According to the [FAQ on WhatsApp's website](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/general/28030001):

> If you are ... preserving your number, you will keep your account info. This information is tied to the phone number. Simply download WhatsApp on the new phone and verify your number.

If you still have your old phone and haven't wiped it, you can also [move your old messages to your new phone](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/android/20887921).